# Powershell output file missing lines from input file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Why would the output file produced by the following script not contain all of the lines that were contained in the original file? I'm doing replacement logic on a line by line level, I'm not explicitely removing any lines though.

```
[regex]$r = "\$\%\$@@(.+)\$\%\$@@";

(Get-Content $inputFile) | 
    Foreach-Object {
        $line = $_;
        $find = $r.matches($line);

        if ($find[0].Success) {
            foreach ($match in $find) {
                $found = $match.value           
                $replace = $found -replace "[^A-Za-z0-9\s]", "";            
                $line.Replace($found, $replace);
            }       
        }
    } | 
Set-Content $outputFile
```

**Input File**

[image: Input File]

**Output File**

[image: Output File]

Comment: What happens to the line if ($find[0].Success) is $false?

Comment: I don't do anything with the line when the condition is false, so I was assuming it would pipe directly to the output file.

Comment: I think you should question that assumption.

Comment: Agreed - I don't think I'm totally understanding exactly what was happening in the Foreach loop.

Comment: You assigned $_ to $line at the beginning of the script block. This line: $line.Replace($found, $replace) is outputting replaced text to the pipeline, but it only runs if there is a match. If there is not a match, nothing gets output to the pipeline, and that line (stored in $line) get overwritten by the next line that comes in from the pipeline.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand. So Write-Output is correct to do in this scenario I would think?

Comment: Or just Else { $line }.  Note that you don't do an explicit Write-Output of $line.replace, but it finds it way to the pipeline just fine without it.

Comment: Else { $line} works also. I'm assuming $line.replace works also because that function returns a string. Reformat your response into an answer, and I'll accept...

Comment: Done.  I could have done that up front, but I wanted you to think about it a little first :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only outputting content to the pipe if it finds a match, at this line:

```
$line.Replace($found, $replace)
```

If there was not a match found, then you need to output the line without doing any replacement:

```
[regex]$r = "\$\%\$@@(.+)\$\%\$@@";

(Get-Content $inputFile) | 
    Foreach-Object {
        $line = $_;
        $find = $r.matches($line);

        if ($find[0].Success) {
            foreach ($match in $find) {
                $found = $match.value           
                $replace = $found -replace "[^A-Za-z0-9\s]", "";            
                $line.Replace($found, $replace);
            }       
        }

        Else { $line }

    } | 
Set-Content $outputFile
```